# Calling a function in functions.php from a page-template's <a> element

Tags: wordpress, function

I created a function to clear a $_SESSION variable and I need to call that function when the user clicks an  element, in case this isn't possible. Can it be done with a button?
Where can I see an example.
Thanks in advance
Omar

Comment: You can use form to start that function.

Comment: and can't it be done with an <a> element?? I prefer that over the button solution

Comment: The user clicks the link in the browser. The PHP runs on the server. There's no connection between the two unless you make one, e.g. Ajax.

Comment: and how can it be done with ajax? 
thanks

Comment: In the case of the button inside the form. What do I need to write to call the function?

Comment: You would need to have a small PHP program on the host that cleared the $_SESSION variable based on a request from the browser. If the session is based on user ID or similar you would need to pass that in with the request. Then you would need JS to send that program an Ajax request when the user clicked the link or pressed the button or whatever you decide to use.

Comment: thanks, if you could point me to an example would be great.